# openpyxl - issue accessing named range?

Tags: python, openpyxl

So I was following the documentation to openpyxl [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/defined_names.html) and wanted to create a named range in a new workbook and just play around with it and understand how it works. Sadly I'm getting an error and I'm not sure what the error means.

Here is the code below:

```
import openpyxl

# create workbook
wb = openpyxl.Workbook() 

# create named range
new_range = openpyxl.workbook.defined_name.DefinedName('newrange',attr_text='Sheet$A$1:$A$5')
wb.defined_names.append(new_range)

list(wb.defined_names['newrange'].destinations)
```

And here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      2 new_range = openpyxl.workbook.defined_name.DefinedName('newrange',attr_text='Sheet$A$1:$A$5')
      3 wb.defined_names.append(new_range)
----> 4 list(wb.defined_names['newrange'].destinations)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/defined_name.py in destinations(self)
    138                 if part.subtype == "RANGE":
    139                     m = SHEETRANGE_RE.match(part.value)
--> 140                     sheetname = m.group('notquoted') or m.group('quoted')
    141                     yield sheetname, m.group('cells')
    142 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Any ideas? Iterating over the generator gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The issue is a missing "!":

```
    new_range = openpyxl.workbook.defined_name.DefinedName('newrange',attr_text='Sheet$A$1:$A$5')
```

should be:

```
    new_range = openpyxl.workbook.defined_name.DefinedName('newrange',attr_text='Sheet!$A$1:$A$5')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/defined_names.html#sample-use-for-ranges):

```py
my_range = wb.defined_names['my_range']
# if this contains a range of cells then the destinations attribute is not None
dests = my_range.destinations # returns a generator of (worksheet title, cell range) tuples
```

This means that `destinations` will return a generator of a range. However, the range you've given returns `None` making it a `NoneType`. Therefore, you haven't given a proper range, or a range that doesn't contain a range of cells.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to find the issue. I edited the main post

Comment: @Ajeet I know that you're new and that's fine! But instead of editing the question saying you found the answer, you mark the check mark next to the answer that helped you. This will help you, and the answerer. However, if you find the answer before someone else does, you answer your own question by clicking the button below.